# TypeError: Could not convert to numeric

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, deep-learning

This is my code:

```
file_path = 'TEST3.csv'  # Update the path to your CSV file
columns = ['Year','T', 'TM', 'Tm', 'PP', 'Yields_Blé_dur']
n_steps_in, n_steps_out = 3, 1
test_set_years = 5


df = load_data(file_path)

# Preprocess the data
df_processed = preprocess_data_columns(df, columns)
# Extract 'Year' for plotting purposes
years = df_processed['Year'].values
```

[this is my database] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZgMR.png)

GitHub Link: https://github.com/Moiz1500/LSTM-model

I got this Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[44], line 10
      7 df = load_data(file_path)
      9 # Preprocess the data
---> 10 df_processed = preprocess_data_columns(df, columns)
     11 # Extract 'Year' for plotting purposes
     12 years = df_processed['Year'].values

Cell In[33], line 2
      1 def preprocess_data_columns(df, columns):
----> 2     df = df[columns].fillna(df.mean())  #Fill NaN values with the mean of the column
      3     return df

File c:\Users\hemic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:11335, in DataFrame.mean(self, axis, skipna, numeric_only, **kwargs)
  11327 @doc(make_doc("mean", ndim=2))
  11328 def mean(
  11329     self,
   (...)
  11333     **kwargs,
  11334 ):
> 11335     result = super().mean(axis, skipna, numeric_only, **kwargs)
  11336     if isinstance(result, Series):
  11337         result = result.__finalize__(self, method="mean")
...
-> 1678     raise TypeError(f"Could not convert {x} to numeric")
   1679 try:
   1680     x = x.astype(np.complex128)

Type Error: Could not convert ['1/1/20121/2/20121/3/201212/31/2023'] to numeric.
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
```

How would I go about fixing this error?

I don't know how I can convert Colum of Year to Date

Comment: Please remove the image and provide the CSV.

Comment: I don't know how I can upload The CSV file.

Comment: If it's too big to copy-paste into the question, you can create a gist (https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: Done : https://github.com/Moiz1500/LSTM-model

Comment: Thanks. Other suggestions to attract answers would be to include required imports, define `columns`, include the function `read_data` in your code, include the function `preprocess_data_columns` in your code (not just in the error message), and ideally to automatically download `TEST3.csv` (e.g. with `urllib`). That is, you could probably avoid all the downvotes by making the code executable.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how I can convert Colum of Year to Date

You can convert the `Year` column to datetimes and thereby avoid the error with [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```py
# assumes import pandas as pd
df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'])
```

before taking the mean.

Preferably, you could be more selective about which columns in which you try to replace NaNs with the mean. The `Year` column doesn't have any NaNs, so you don't even need to compute the mean.

The following code executes without warning or error with Pandas 1.5.3.

```py
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Moiz1500/LSTM-model/main/TEST3.csv'
file_path = 'TEST3.csv'
urlretrieve(url, file_path)

def preprocess_data_columns(df, columns):
    df[columns] = df[columns].fillna(df[columns].mean())
    return df

df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'])

# Preprocess the data
columns = df.columns[1:]
df_processed = preprocess_data_columns(df, columns)
# Extract 'Year' for plotting purposes
years = df_processed['Year'].values
years
```

Comment: I got the same Error, please check GitHub link : https://github.com/Moiz1500/LSTM-model

Comment: You need to do it before calling `preprocess_data_columns`. I don't know what `load_data` does, if not just `pd.read_csv`, so maybe you are doing something else that makes it fail. See the updated solution - just don't try to `fillna` in the `Year` column.

Comment: I don't have any Idea about this problem but I'll try